# FontAwesome using CDN doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, font-awesome

As the title says, I have problem displaying FontAwesome in Firefox. I have tried many solutions found here and on the web and it still doesn't work. I tried with this simple page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.css?ver=3.8.4" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>

<body>
<span><i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i></span>
</body>
</html>
```

It does work on Chrome but not in Firefox. I need to load it using CDN, and already checked it using Firebug the font is loaded fine (status 200 OK), but it is not displayed correctly. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `<link>` tag with this one that works on both Chrome and Firefox.

`<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work either. Thanks anyway for your reply.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code to my localhost and got the correct output. Is there anything else you are doing? The icon should still show a character even if the link is incorrect.